# CSV file, not keeping leading zeros, what do do

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have no idea what to do. Please see below. I need to import this file into another system with the leading zeros. These are sample zip codes as well. I have no idea what is going on. It seems to be an excel issue with CSV files. How can I preseve the leading zeros on a CSV file? Thanks for your help. I haven't had this issue before.

```
XLSX File
POSTAL_CODE_FORMATTED_TEXT and POSTAL_CODE_FORMATTED_Number
07717
```

Please see CSV file

```
CSV File
POSTAL_CODE_FORMATTED_TEXT and POSTAL_CODE_FORMATTED_Number
7717
```

Comment: Looks like this is a common problem in excel. When I opened it up with notepad, it does have the leading zeros. Looks like it's just an issue with excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the edit the column manually you can follow the below steps

1. Highlight the column
2. Right click and select format cells
3. On the "Number" tab go to "Custom"

4: Under where it says "Type:" you can enter the amount of digits you want to appear in the column (ex: 00000)